# mongodb already exists array added another value query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have notification click table like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d00d4e1d720cc4cb1b24566"),
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2019-06-12T10:33:05.866Z"),
    "notification_center_id" : [ 
        ObjectId("5c59343523f05e2ff13938d6")
    ],
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5bc5dc03f6d24d29077dd362"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to check if user_id "5bc5dc03f6d24d29077dd362" is already exists then added another notification_center_id in already exists record.

like this

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d00d4e1d720cc4cb1b24566"),
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2019-06-12T10:33:05.866Z"),
    "notification_center_id" : [ 
        ObjectId("5c59343523f05e2ff13938d6"),
        ObjectId("5c5c4610c6d91403f38eda52")
    ],
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5bc5dc03f6d24d29077dd362"),
    "__v" : 0
 }
```

I want query that first check user id exists if exists then added another notification record in notification_center_id field.
If user is not exists then I want add another record in collection
one more condition here, if notification_center_id is not inserted duplicate. if it's exist then not added.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
    {"user_id" : ObjectId("5bc5dc03f6d24d29077dd362")},
    {"$push" : {"notification_center_id" : new ObjectId()}}
)
```

In your question, you have not mentioned what to do if user_id doesn't exist. So doing nothing in that case.

After your comment

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
    {"user_id" : ObjectId("5c59343523f05e2ff13938d6")},
    {
        "$push" : {"notification_center_id" : new ObjectId()},
        "$setOnInsert" : {"createdOn" : new ISODate(), "__v" : 0}
    },
    {"upsert" : true}
)
```

Comment: if user not exists then I want to add another record in collection

Comment: Edited answer, check now

Comment: - it's give me error "ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined"
 mongodb version : db version v4.0.9

Comment: NotificationClick.update(
                        {"_id" : cdata[0]._id },
                        {"$push" : {"notification_center_id" : ObjectId(req.body.notification_id) }}
                    ).exec(function (err, adddata) { 

                    });


**
it's working. but if i want to check "notification_center_id" is already exists then not updated. in this query. then what should i do ? **

Answer (score 0):

$addToSet update operator is used to append an element to an array and preserves uniqueness of values into an array.

```
db.notifications.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5d00d4e1d720cc4cb1b24566")}
, { $addToSet: { notification_center_id: new ObjectId() } })
```